# Using snap point when using measurecontrol in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2

I have a problem about measurecontrol. I can use measurecontrol and I can show length to use measure control . But my problem is that I didn't use in snap because measurecontrol is a control, not a layer.

```
    measureControl = new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(
        OpenLayers.Handler.Path,
        {
            immediate: true,
            persist: true
        }
    );  

    measureControl.getCustomLength = function(evt) {
        var str = '';
        str = 'Toplam: ' + (evt.units === 'km' ? evt.measure.toFixed(3) : evt.measure.toFixed(1)) + ' ' + evt.units + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
           // uzunluk =evt.units ==='km';
            uzunluk=evt.measure;
        return str;
    }
    map.addControl(measureControl);
    measureControl.events.on({
        'measure': function(evt) {
            $("#mesafe").html(measureControl.getCustomLength(evt));
        }
    });
    measureControl.activate();
```

This is my measure control. And I want to snap this to point to my another vector. So when I look openlayer's snap:

```
    var snap = new OpenLayers.Control.Snapping({
        layer: measurecontrollayer,
        targets: [{
            layer:mylayer,
            tolerance: 15
            }]
        });
        snap.activate();
```

snap is using only vector but my measurecontrol is not a vector. Please show me some way to achieve this. Also is there another way to use measure in layer linestring layer?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i want to say measurecontrol  is not using on snapp control. So you create own your linestring like that

```
          var lineLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer");  

            drawControls = {
            line: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer,
                    OpenLayers.Handler.Path)

            };
              $("#yollayer").click(function(){
            drawControls.line.activate();
            });
             $("#mapDiv").dblclick(function(){
            //var line = lineLayer.features[0].geometry.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject());
            var line =lineLayer.features[0].geometry;
            var dist = line.getLength();
            uzunluk=dist/1000;
            alert(dist/1000);
            }); 

            map.addControl(drawControls.line);
            map.addLayers([lineLayer]);`
```

be careful line.getlength() result is meter distanceee .This is give you when u draw linestring in lineLayer result is meausure this linestring.

Then you must add snapp control like that .

```
            snap = new OpenLayers.Control.Snapping({
            layer: lineLayer,
            targets: [kullaniciparsel],
            greedy: false
        });
        snap.activate();

        // add some editing tools to a panel
        var panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
            displayClass: "olControlEditingToolbar"
        });
        modify = new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(
            lineLayer, {displayClass: "olControlModifyFeature", title: "Modify Features"}
        );  `
```

Dont remember snap contral layer must be editable layer . This is result .When you draw linestring automatically snapping your target layer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [your answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/51977/115). While your solution was that Measure doesn't use the Snapping Control, it seems to me, that in my application this is not true. When I disable the OpenLayers.Control.Snapping, then no snapping occurs. So it is used.

The only difference to your application is, that I use the [DynamicMeasure.js](https://github.com/jorix/OL-DynamicMeasure) lib which extends the Measure.js from OpenLayers but doesn't change the Snap-Handling.

By the way: I am using OpenLayers 2.13 in my example